# How do a compare a char to a number? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, list, if-statement, char

in my current program I have the user input a number that gets stored in a char list. After that I go through the list and try to assign that number to an int variable. That is where I run into an error. This is an excerpt of my code.

```
        if (list1[j]=='1');
            z=1;
        if (list1[j]=='2');
            z=2;
        if (list1[j]=='3');
            z=3;
        if (list1[j]=='4');
            z=4;
```

The issue is that z always becomes 4 even if list[j]=3. I know I am making a mistake my comparisons but I've been unable to locate it. I would appreciate your help.

This is how I define the list:

```
    char list1[32];
```

And this is how I fill it up:

```
    for(int i=0;i<(2*c);i+=2)
{
    cin>>list1[i]>>list1[i+1];
}
```

Comment: Remove the semi-colons from your if statements.

Comment: Drop semicolons after closing paren: `if (list1[j]=='1') /* no semicolon here */`

Comment: Yes, my bad. However, what it does now is it always considers the number to be 1 instead of 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your `if` statements with a single math line:

```
z = list1[j] - '0';
```

This works for most encodings.

Note: the above statement only works with single digit characters.

**Edit 1:  `switch` vs. `if`**
If you insist on comparing, I believe a `switch` would be more readable:

```
switch (list[j])
{
  case '1': z = 1; break;
  case '2': z = 2; break;
  case '3': z = 3; break;
  // ...
}
```

The single statement above is still less code, less chances for defects.

Comment: I will try that now!

Comment: Just tried both suggestions - they both work. I've never liked switch but It is obviously very efficient in scenarios like these.
Thanks very much for your help, I will accept the answer once stackoverflow allows me.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is drop the semicolons from your if statements. If you include the semicolon after each if statement the code-block in the if statement won't execute.  It should look like this:

```
if (list1[j]=='1')
    z=1;
if (list1[j]=='2')
    z=2;
if (list1[j]=='3')
    z=3;
if (list1[j]=='4')
    z=4;
```

Comment: I did, It only changed the problem to always having z be equal to 1. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: The answer below mine should actually sort out your issue.  I recommend you give that a try(: